# Helping Kohana 3 ORM to speed up a little

Tags: kohana-3, kohana-orm

I noticed that Kohana 3 ORM runs a "SHOW FULL COLUMNS" for each of my models when I start using them:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `mytable`
```

This query might take a few clock cycles to execute (in the Kohana profiler it's actually the slowest of all queries ran in my current app).

Is there a way to help Kohana 3 ORM to speed up by disabling this behaviour and explicitly define the columns in my models instead?

Comment: http://kohanaframework.org/guide/api/ORM check out there, $_table_columns might be what you're looking for.

Comment: http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/comment/19555/#Comment_19555

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**biakaveron** answered my question with a comment so I can't except the correct answer.

Taken from Wouters answer on the official Kohana forums (where biakaveron pointed to), this is the correct answer:

> It's very easy, `$table_columns` is a
>   big array with a lot of info, but
>   actually only very little of this info
>   is used in ORM.
>
> This will do:

```
protected $_table_columns = array(
    'id'            =>  array('type'=>'int'),
    'name'          =>  array('type'=>'string'),
    'allowNull'     =>  array('type'=>'string','null'=>TRUE),
    'created'       =>  array('type'=>'int')
);
```

Comment: I've ticked this as the correct answer since it answers the question in the best possible way, whether it's useful or not.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't too much overhead when that query gets executed; though you can cache them / skip the process by defining them manually (if that is really what you want override the `$_table_columns` in your models, though I don't see how much time you can save doing it - it's worth trying).

I proposed a caching alternative for `list_columns()` but it got denied as it really isn't that much of a bottleneck: http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/2848

Comment: The reason I brought it up is when I used the profiler and ran a half dozen queries for a single request, the SHOW FULL COLUMNS query was the slowest.

Answer (score 1):

do not forget underscore:

```
protected $_table_columns = array(
    'id'            =>  array('type'=>'int'),
    'name'          =>  array('type'=>'string'),
    'allowNull'     =>  array('type'=>'string','null'=>TRUE),
    'created'       =>  array('type'=>'int')
);
```

This will give you full column
info as an array:

```
var_export($ORM->list_columns());
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the kohana team said 'show full columns' runs as fast reading from cache for all cases. Query cache is a bottleneck on mysql for our workload due to . So we had to turn it off.

https://blogs.oracle.com/dlutz/entry/mysql_query_cache_sizing

Proof that show full columns is the most run query
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zn0pbiogt774ne4/Screenshot%202015-02-17%2018.56.21.png?dl=0

Proof of the temp tables on the disk from NewRelic mysql plugin. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cwo09sy9qxboeds/Screenshot%202015-02-17%2019.00.19.png?dl=0

And the top offending queries (> 100ms) sorted by query count.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1kpmkef4jd8uvt/Screenshot%202015-02-17%2018.55.38.png?dl=0