# kohana columns introspection

Tags: kohana-orm

I would like to know which is the functionality of the $_table_columns array on a KOHANA model.

I ask this since the table's columns are loaded by introspection, what is the use of this array, is it for default values to the properties?

Answer (score 0):

`$_table_columns` reflects your table column structure. So if your table has 3 columns (id, name, desc), `$_table_columns` will be setup to `array('id' => '', 'name' => '', 'desc' => '')`.

By default `$_table_columns` is an empty array. When you extend ORM with your class and don't override `$_table_columns`, it will be automatically filled by ORM by calling `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM table_name` command. If you want to avoid this additional DB call, you can initialize `$_table_columns` on your own:

```
class Model_User extends ORM {
   protected $_table_columns = array('id' => '', 'name' => '', 'desc' => '');
}
```

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892708/helping-kohana-3-orm-to-speed-up-a-little) for more details.

Comment: I tried what you said matino, but for example if I add 3 columns to $_table_columns and my table has 4 columns, when I ask for the colum that is not on the array it still brings the value, that is why I have that question, do you know what is that happening?